# How to send data from page to an other?

Tags: reactjs

In page ( Datatable.jsx ), i have this state:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

I want to send this `data` to an other page ( Single.jsx ), how to do that?

Comment: You can pass the `data` as a prop if the `Single.jsx` is the child of the `Datatable.jsx`.
And, of course you can use global state management such as `redux`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different ways of doing that.

The first solution is to create a parent component which contains the state you want to share. Here is an example :

```
function ParentComponent(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  return (
    <>
      <Dashboard data={data} />     
      <Single data={data} />
    </>
  );
}
```

An other solution is to use [React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

There are other state management solutions that exists such as [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).